# Page Indicator UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller in my iPhone app. The view is defined using the Interface Builder and a class to manage it. This class extends

```
UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
```

I used the following functions for page indicator.

```
-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {}
-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {}
```

However, the number of pages in my application increased and the page indicator goes out of my current view (the starting and the ending dots). Is there any way I can use similar display to line break in labels etc. Any alternatives to page indicator are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your own page indicator.