# UIPageViewController page indicator out of sync

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

My UIPageViewController's page indicator goes out of sync when swiping back and forth really fast using this UIAutomation script:

```
target.dragFromToForDuration({x:10, y:100}, {x:300, y:114}, 0.5);
target.dragFromToForDuration({x:300, y:100}, {x:10, y:114}, 0.5);
```

repeated over and over.

Or when tapping one direction on the page controller and swiping the other direction as in this question:
[UIPageControl and UIPageviewController are out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891756/uipagecontrol-and-uipageviewcontroller-are-out-of-sync)

The solution there was to replace the page indicator with a UIPageControl. This solution was also accepted here:
[Page Indicator UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235816/page-indicator-uipageviewcontroller)

My code for returning the UIViewControllers (the UIViewControllers contain tables with different data sources):

```
- (MyViewController*) viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    MyViewController *pageContentViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    id myDataSource = [self.myDataSources objectAtIndex:index];
    [pageContentViewController setMyDataSource:myDataSource];

    return pageContentViewController;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    id myDataSource = [((MyViewController*) viewController) myDataSource];
    NSInteger index = [self.myDataSources indexOfObject:myDataSource];

    if (index == NSNotFound || index - 1 < 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        MyViewController *pageContentViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index - 1];
        return pageContentViewController;
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    MyDataSource *myDataSource = [((MyViewController*) viewController) myDataSource];
    NSInteger index = [self.myDataSources indexOfObject:myDataSource];

    if (index == NSNotFound || index + 1 >= [self.myDataSources count]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        MyViewController *pageContentViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index + 1];
        return pageContentViewController;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

What is causing the UIPageViewController and page indicator to become out of sync?

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498420/5329717